# Error TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null when add text innerHTML using javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
<textarea name="widget-generalcode" cols="50" rows="13" id="widget-generalcode"></textarea>
```

and javascript

```
<script>
document.getElementById('widget-generalcode').innnerHTML = 'test';
</script>
```

When I run code, error `TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null`, how to fix it ?

Comment: Please make sure that your <script> is below the <textarea> and the textarea is not "innerHTML" it's "value"

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LmfKe/ try this for example

Answer (score 3):

May be you should put it on pageload:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById('widget-generalcode').innerHTML = 'test';
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should consider where you place javascript statements. 
It will effect to the desired result.
I recommended that you should use web development tool such as Firebug in Firefox (press F12)
It will help you to debug javascript code and you can use Timeline feature to detect which parts of your Html/javascript "spent" a lot of resources.
Hope this information is useful.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check that your JavaScript is executed when DOM is loaded. One option is to put your `<script>` tag just before `</body>`.

Then, you should use `value` property for form fields:

```
document.getElementById("widget-generalcode").value = "test";
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to access the element before it is rendered on your page so you will never get that element so write your code in function as below

```
<script>
  function call()
  {
    document.getElementById('widget-generalcode').value = 'test';
  } 
</script>
```

and now in body tag palce onload ="call()" as given below it will work

```
<body onload ="call()" >

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm new  2 Stackoverflow

In asp.net Actualy Startup is my id but on clientside it will be displayed as ctl00_dmrcontent_Startup
so in ur script change id form widget-generalcode to what display in clientside

```
<div  id="Startup" runat="server">
```

Answer (score 0):

This caused me much grief. It's a matter of understanding the sequence of execution of the "onLoad" (which occurs after all the PHP has been executed and turned into HTML), and the running of a js command after say parsing the url parameters (which occurs before onLoad).

Answer (score 0):

The javascript function ran before the html page with rendered by the browser.  So the element with the id="widget-generalcode" did not exist when the code ran.

Use window.unload= functionName at the top of your javscript file, *without* parentheses ().  This tells the browser to run the function *after* the html page loads.  This way the html element will exist when the function runs and the javascript can act on it.